# How to prevent Live Writer from messing up <code>

Tags: plugins, wordpress, source-code, windows-live-writer

I am trying out Windows Live Writer, and it seems to be pretty cool. But, how can I prevent it from encoding characters between `<code>` tags when switching between Edit and Source?

Is there a code plug-in that is compatible with the WordPress [CodeColorer](http://kpumuk.info/projects/wordpress-plugins/codecolorer/) plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

When you flip between Edit and Source the encoding might be due to Live Writer replacing them by default.

Go to the menu and then:

> Tools > Options > Editing

[image: options dialog]

In the Editing section uncheck the option **Replace other special characters**.

You may also want to uncheck **Replace "straight quotes" with “smart quotes”**.

Click **OK** and return to flipping between view modes on your post.

Comment: But this will mean that it won't replace these characters outside of `<code>` tags too, right?

Comment: Sadly yeah, kind of a catch-all non-distinguish thing right now.